# Cypress: Another button is not enabled when ticking a checkbox

Tags: selenium, e2e-testing, cypress

I have UI where I have a list of items (via checkbox) and when you ticked a checkbox, then another button (Approve) will be enabled. Until you have not ticked a checkbox, the Approve button remains disabled.

Before ticking the checkbox, the attributes below:

Checkbox A (class is not selected):

```
<tr id="row1" class>
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem" value="d9d8eac0-fc23-413b-a417-1f3ceb30d847" id="id001">
```

Approve button (with disabled attribute):

```
<div class="small thin skip js-actionButton button disabled" id="approve-button">
<a href="#" id="ext-id002"><em class="none">&nbsp;</em>
<span class="text" automation-id="Approve-button">Approve</span></a></div>
```

After ticking the checkbox, the attributes below:

Checkbox A (class is set to selected):

```
<tr id="row1" class=" selected">
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem" value="d9d8eac0-fc23-413b-a417-1f3ceb30d847" id="id001">
```

Approve button (with disabled attribute gone):

```
<div class="small thin skip js-actionButton button" id="approve-button">
<a href="#" id="ext-id002"><em class="none">&nbsp;</em>
<span class="text" automation-id="Approve-button">Approve</span></a></div>
```

This works in Selenium, but for some reason, I can't make it work using Cypress (the Approve button remains disabled). My code below:

```
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check(['d9d8eac0-fc23-413b-a417-1f3ceb30d847']);
cy.get('[automation-id="Approve-button"]').click();
```

screenshot with cypress: [With Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7NLB.png)

screenshot with manual/selenium: [Selenium or Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY1wz.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="bridge-lower">
  <div class="action-bar" style="padding-top:4px;" id="ext-gen114">
    <div class="small thin skip js-actionButton disabled button" id="ext-gen71">
    <a href="#" onclick="CompanyN.widget.Tables.bulkUpdateToJs(this, 'ItemPrint.PrintItemsFromForm(&quot;selectedItems&quot;, false, &quot;Bill&quot;);', 'print', false, true); return false;" id="ext-gen72">
    <em class="none">&nbsp;</em>
    <span class="text" automation-id="Print-button">Print</span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div id="ItemPay-pay-container">
      <div class="small thin skip js-actionButton disabled button" id="ItemPay-bills-button">
      <a href="#" id="ext-gen73"><em class="none">&nbsp;</em><span class="text" automation-id="Approve-button">Approve</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <table class="standard" id="ext-gen79">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td class="thin"><input type="checkbox" id="ext-gen115"></td>
    <td class=" ">
    <a href="/Search.aspx?ItemStatus=ItemSTATUS%2fAPPROVED&amp;graphSearch=False&amp;dateWithin=any&amp;pageSize=25&amp;orderby=ItemNumber&amp;direction=ASC">Ref
    </a>
    </td>
    <td class=" selected">
    <a href="/Search.aspx?ItemStatus=ItemSTATUS%2fAPPROVED&amp;graphSearch=False&amp;dateWithin=any&amp;pageSize=25&amp;orderby=ItemDate&amp;direction=ASC">Date
    </a>
    <span class="icons descend">&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="date ">
    <a href="/Search.aspx?ItemStatus=ItemSTATUS%2fAPPROVED&amp;graphSearch=False&amp;dateWithin=any&amp;pageSize=25&amp;orderby=PayDate&amp;direction=ASC">Pay Date
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="row1" class="">
        <td id="ext-gen81"><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem" value="9cd1075a-f047-46ab-82fc-ea4bd6760b0c" id="ext-gen82">
        <input type="hidden" id="reference_9cd1075a-f047-46ab-82fc-ea4bd6760b0c" value="REFERENCE/PAY"></td>
        <td id="ext-gen83">Reference 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2" class="">
        <td id="ext-gen98"><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem" value="08e10c45-7777-4e3d-8045-f253413fd73e" id="ext-gen99">
        <input type="hidden" id="reference_08e10c45-7777-4e3d-8045-f253413fd73e" value="REFERENCE/PAY"></td>
        <td id="ext-gen100">Reference 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox id is `unique`, you could try below and try to verify/ click the `approve-button` inside the promise part of cypress.

```
cy.get('#id001').click().then(()=>{
    cy.get('#approve-button').should('be.visible');
   // or if you want to click:
    cy.get('#approve-button').click();
})
```

Or if I understand from the question, that the check box is inside the `<tr>` element, then you may try the below code:

```
cy.get('#row1 > input[type="checkbox"]').check().then(()=>{
        cy.get('#approve-button').should('be.visible');
         // or if you want to click on the button
        cy.get('#approve-button').click();
})
```

// As you said you can click on checkbox, please try below case and let me know, if this is not working please post html

```
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check(['d9d8eac0-fc23-413b-a417-1f3ceb30d847']).then(($el)=>{
    cy.wrap($el).find('#approve-button').should('be.visible');
 })
```

// In your html id for that approve button is `automation-id` and when I add to my html it not identifed as html tag. Can you try the below, i have added wait to display the approve button just in case and grab the following id `#ItemPay-bills-button`

```
cy.get('table > tbody > #row1 > td > input[type="checkbox"]').check().then(()=>{
                cy.wait(3000);
                cy.get('#ItemPay-bills-button').should('be.visible');
                    // or if you want to click on the button
                cy.get('#ItemPay-bills-button').click();
            })
```

Comment: Thanks but both did not work. For the first one, I am not sure why the click method should be used in this scenario. For the 2nd one, unable to find the element with id="row1" even if it is visible on the page. Lastly, the assertion on "should be visible" is not the problem here but more on, for some reason, cypress is still not making it visible even if a checkbox is already ticked.

Comment: Could you add the full HTML

Comment: Is that checkbox is nested inside div elements. Could you please add the full html

Comment: Yes, it is nested inside multiple div elements. I'll find a way to add the full html. Just a note that my command to tick the checkbox works so definitely it can find that element. `cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check(['d9d8eac0-fc23-413b-a417-1f3ceb30d847']);` the problem is that the "Approve-button" remains disabled after ticking that checkbox. It should be enabled as what can happen using Selenium and manual check.

Comment: Thanks, this works same as my other code where the ticking of the checkbox works. The problem is the event that happens afterwards where the "Approve" button remains disabled. I suspect it is the way Cypress calls the elements. I have attached the screenshots. I am still trying to find ways to include the full HTML in a masked way.

Comment: No this screenshot will not help.  You might want to  right click on the table or element >  choose inspect > Got the elements tab in console > click and right click of the html tag  > Copy > Copy element and paste in your question.  You can remove any project related information, but would like to see the html structure

Comment: Sorry took a while but I have uploaded the HTML section. Check if it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: i have provided the HTML at the end of my post

Comment: Will look again soon

Comment: Your solution is a cleaner way to tick the checkbox and it works. However, the Approve button is still disabled. If you go back to my screenshots, it seems like using Selenium (and manual), the whole of row 1 is highlighted and I believe that is the one that triggers the Approve button to be enabled. How do I highlight it in Cypress based on the HTML above? Again, thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: Hmm, to do more I need to have access with real site I guess , not able  guess anything else ...do you have an url for the site?

Answer (score 0):

From Cypress v4.6.0 and above, this worked by bypassing the integrity check on the script file:

```
{
  "experimentalSourceRewriting": true
}
```

Include the above on your `cypress.json` file